# How to remove error too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

Applied LDA model usinf TFIDF and then I want Performance evaluation by classifying sample document using LDA TF-IDF model.

Code:

```
for index, score in sorted(lda_model_tfidf[corpus], key=lambda tup: -1*tup[1]):
    print("\nScore: {}\t \nTopic: {}".format(score, lda_model_tfidf.print_topic(index, 2)))
```

```
Error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-4d905dbcd194> in <module>
----> 1 for index, score in sorted(lda_model_tfidf[corpus], key=lambda tup: -1*tup[1]):
      2     print("\nScore: {}\t \nTopic: {}".format(score, lda_model_tfidf.print_topic(index, 2)))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing `for a,b in something`, what you do is iterate the items of `something` and expect each item to be itself an iterable (list or tuple) of size two (and assign the value of the first element to `a` and the value of the second to `b`).

Since you don't give the content of `lda_model_tfidf[corpus]` it is hard to debug for us, but you can take look at it and see if each of its items are indeed tuples or lists of size 2. According to the error message you're getting, it seems that there is at least one item of size one in `lda_model_tfidf[corpus]`